# AWS CLI --profile with duration > 1h

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

With the AWS CLI you can assume a role using the `--profile` parameter:

```
aws --profile <profile_name> <service> <command>
```

e.g.:

```
aws --profile admin s3 ls s3://mybucket/
```

That profile can be an AWS role that os to be assumed. My problem with that is that the session of the role is only valid for one hour by default. Is there a way of explicitly setting the session duration without using the `sts` service directly?

Comment: BTW, this is a feature request on the AWS CLI: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3307

Answer (score 1):

You can set a maximum duration of up to 12 hours in the IAM Role config:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you set that on the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Along with changing the  MaxSessionDuration(as mentioned in the above answer) of the IAM role ,also try adding/changing "duration_seconds"  parameter value in the credentials file of the configured profile.